# How to add an object element to nested field array

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I'm trying to push an object element to a nested field array but Typescript keeps complaining about it.

```js
await <PrismaClient>.user.upsert({
  // where: ...
  update: {
    shop: {
      items: {
        push: {
          name: "example"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // create: ...
});
```

TS complains:

```
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type '(...items: ItemCreateInput[]) => number'.
```

Schema:

```
model User {
  id   String @id @map("_id")
  shop Shop

  @@map("users")
}

type Shop {
  items Item[]
}

type Item {
  name String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript error tells you what you need to know: Prisma expects you to pass in variables of type `ItemCreateInput[]`, but you're not doing that now. If your code editor has TypeScript intellisense, you can command+click on the `upsert` operation and dig deeper into the arguments that Prisma expects you to pass. Alternatively, you can search the newly opened file for `ItemCreateInput`, though this may take a while depending on the size of your schema.

If you need to create related items at the same time as creating/updating/upserting a different item, there is no `push` operation for this. You're probably looking for `create`. Your operation is going to look something like this:

```js
await <PrismaClient>.user.upsert({
  // where: ...
  update: {
    shop: {
      items: {
        create: {
          name: "example"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // create: ...
});
```

Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-single-record-and-multiple-related-records

Comment: But the `items` field in this schema is just an embedded array of objects, it does not relate to any other collection so it doesn't need to create other documents elsewhere. Please correct me if I'm miss understanding something, am new to Prisma, thank you!

Comment: I don't think Prisma has a `type XXX` concept, only `model XXX` concept, in which case it would be relational (even if it was MongoDB or something else.) Check out the Prisma documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model

Comment: I found the composite type concept for MongoDB here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#type

Comment: Ah, I'm completely wrong then, didn't even know that was a thing. It seems like the generated Prisma client will still be pretty similar, so I recommend looking at the compiled TypeScript to figure out what the actual interface for using this data is supposed to be